# Cocos2d Resources

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Any recommendations on good sites/resources on programming with the Cocos2d-iPhone game engine?

What worked for you? What is the canonical place for all things Cocos2d? Any sites you recommend? Best practices? Blogs?

Much appreciated

Comment: This is the direct link to the online API reference for cocos2d iphone. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/index.html hopefully someone that stumbles upon this post finds this useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have used those sites and have also found Ray Wenderlich's tutorials very useful.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

Also there are several references available here too:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/resources:iphone_recommended_reading

Happy coding! B)

ADDITION:
I found these two questions have many great resources too:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2326/1037

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/20/1037

Answer (score 6):

I've found monitoring #cocos2d on Twitter can sometimes turn up some interesting articles.  Cocos2D blog is usually pretty active and points out available tutorials once and a while like the following...

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/582

Take a look through their wiki as there is a bunch of useful articles there as well...

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/

Answer (score 4):

Cocos2d [forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/) worked for most of my issues. riq, the author of Cocos is there answering many questions.

Answer (score 4):

I have a Cocos2d Resources page that i keep updating as i find new material and learn more:

http://www.gaminghorror.net/cocos2d-iphone-resources/

I'm sharing the generally re-usable parts of my source code together with cleaned up and bugfixed modifications or rewrites of other's code (credits given) as well as any link that i've used or find useful for cocos2d developers. I don't stop at cocos2d though, i also post links to solutions for issues every iPhone developer will come across sooner or later.