# cocos2d customize switch

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i need to create a switch over cocos2d scene. i can create a uiswitch and add it to scene but
i really interested in cocos2d switch if there is any....

can anyone give me any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile and run the cocs2d test applications included with cocos2d there are several tests that use controls like a switch or a slider.  Then you can look at the test files and see how they implemented.

Best way I have been learning cocos2d is by reviewing the test apps.

Also check out these posts for several other useful resources:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293457/cocos2d-resources/4061868#4061868t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293457/cocos2d-resources/4061868#4061868)
[Need 2D iPhone graphics designed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104124/need-2d-iphone-graphics-designed/4111974#4111974)